# How to iterate array in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to iterate array in json:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#wardno').change(function(){ //any select change on the dropdown with id country trigger this code         
        $("#wardname > option").remove(); //first of all clear select items
        var ward_id = $('#wardno').val(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url:"get_wardname/"+ward_id, //here we are calling our user controller and get_cities method with the country_id
            success: function(cities) { 
                try {   
                    $.each(cities,function(id,city) {
                        var opt = $('<option />'); // here we're creating a new select option with for each city
                        opt.val(id[0]);
                        opt.text(id[1]);
                        $('#wardname').append(opt);
                        var opt1 = $('<option />'); // here we're creating a new select option with for each city
                        opt1.val(city[0]);
                        opt1.text(city[1]);
                        $('#koottaymaname').append(opt1);
                    });
//here we will append these new select options to a dropdown with the id 'cities'
                } catch(e) {        
                    alert(e);
                }       
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("jqXHR: " + jqXHR.status + "\ntextStatus: " + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown: " + errorThrown);
            }   
        });   
    });
});
```

The output from the code is:

```
[{"1":"St. Sebastian"},{"1":"kudumbakoottayma1","2":"kudumbakoottayma2"}]
```

How to iterate into two different drop down list?

Comment: Why you tagged it as PHP and codeigniter? This is js not php or codeigniter

Comment: sorry first time stackoverflow

Comment: Is it correct output?

Comment: How you getting different number of sets

Comment: @KajaMydeen: its calling from databse

Comment: Please read [ask]. Be more specific because *"How to iterate array in json"* is simply too broad. We don't know what is or isn't working in your code if you don't explain where your actual problem is and what difficulty you are having

Answer (score 0):

right way

```
$.each(cities, function(index, value) {
    console.log(cities[index]);
    //or
    console.log(value);
});
```

but you are using wrong way

```
$.each(cities, function(id, city) {
    console.log(id[0]);
});
```

it is impossible to use a array or object as index.